# Load numpy array from pandas dataframe into tensorflow dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to load my pandas dataframe (df) into a Tensorflow dataset with the following command:

```
target = df['label']
features = df['encoded_sentence']

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features.values, target.values))
```

Here's an excerpt from my pandas dataframe:

```
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
| label | sentence              | encoded_sentence |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 0     | Hello world           | [5, 7]           |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 1     | my name is john smith | [1, 9, 10, 2, 6] |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 1     | Hello! My name is     | [5, 3, 9, 10]    |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 0     | foo baar              | [8, 4]           |
+-------+-----------------------+------------------+

# df.dtypes gives me:
label                int8
sentence             object
encoded_sentencee    object
```

But it keeps giving me a Value Error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the encoded sentences in my Tensorflow dataset? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your Pandas values into a ragged tensor first and then make the dataset from it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'sentence': ['Hello world', 'my name is john smith',
                                'Hello! My name is', 'foo baar'],
                   'encoded_sentence': [[5, 7], [1, 9, 10, 2, 6],
                                        [5, 3, 9, 10], [8, 4]]})
features = tf.ragged.stack(list(df['encoded_sentence']))
target = tf.convert_to_tensor(df['label'].values)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, target))
for f, t in dataset:
    print(f.numpy(), t.numpy())
```

Output:

```
[5 7] 0
[ 1  9 10  2  6] 1
[ 5  3  9 10] 1
[8 4] 0
```

Note you may want to use [`padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) to get batches of examples from the dataset.

EDIT: Since padded-batching does not seem to work with a dataset made from a ragged tensor at the moment, you can also convert the ragged tensor to a regular one first:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'sentence': ['Hello world', 'my name is john smith',
                                'Hello! My name is', 'foo baar'],
                   'encoded_sentence': [[5, 7], [1, 9, 10, 2, 6],
                                        [5, 3, 9, 10], [8, 4]]})
features_ragged = tf.ragged.stack(list(df['encoded_sentence']))
features = features_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=-1)
target = tf.convert_to_tensor(df['label'].values)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, target))
batches = dataset.batch(2)
for f, t in batches:
    print(f.numpy(), t.numpy())
```

Output:

```
[[ 5  7 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1  9 10  2  6]] [0 1]
[[ 5  3  9 10 -1]
 [ 8  4 -1 -1 -1]] [1 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When I try to create a batch it gives me a type error...
`TypeError: ('Padded batching of components of type ', <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensorSpec'>, ' is not supported.')`
Can you tell the correct way to create a train and test set?

Comment: @StudentAsker I see, I'd say that is a bug, I filed [issue #39163](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39163).

Comment: @StudentAsker I added an alternative simply converting the ragged tensor into a regular one.